# can we say "a fish hops"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the above picture.

There was a fish which jumped out of the water and landed onto another spot in the shape of a curve.

That movement of the fish looks like a hop.

But we often say "**a frog hops**" or "**a rabbit hops**".

Can we say "**a fish hops**"?

Answer (score 5):

'Hopping' is normally associated with using your *feet*, which fish do not have. It can mean jumping using one foot, or jumping from one foot to the other.

We would normally say that a fish 'jumped' out of the water, and although the etymology of the word 'hop' does incorporate the meanings of *springing* and *leaping*, the way it is used in modern speech just doesn't quite fit with a fish jumping. I'm not saying that nobody *ever* says it... but it's definitely not common and wouldn't be my word choice in connection with a fish.

For the avoidance of doubt, here's an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fish+jumping%2C+fish+hopping%2C+fish+hopped%2C+fish+jumped&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) of Google Books showing the variation in usage between 'fish jumping' and 'fish hopping'. As you will see, 'hopping' is almost a flat line at 0.

Comment: @fertilizerspike that wasn't really what I said. I was trying to explain a fact that already exists - the fact that almost nobody seems to say 'hopping' in connection with fish. Have a look at the ngram I've added to my answer. Ngrams don't prove it's wrong or right, but they show what is commonly used across a decent sample of literature. So, having established that people say 'jumping' and almost never 'hopping', I think its reasonable to say that's because hopping is normally associated with pedalism.

Comment: There is of course a species of [flying fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_fish). But I believe that they too are said to jump - for that is what they do - and then glide through the air aided by extensive fin structures.

Comment: Looking at fertilizerspike's collection of links below, it seems that when people do colloquially use "hopping" for fish, it's associated with movement into or out of a vessel or container, and not general movement the way it is for a rabbit or frog. When dolphins or seals jump repeatedly in this manner, it's referred to as "porpoising."

Comment: @katy Absolutely - an entirely different use of the word. A measured journey in a vehicle from one specific place to another can also be called a 'hop'.

Answer (score -2):

Describing a fish as "hopping" has common usage in very large regions of English speakers. Even more common is to say "jumping". Either will be understood by many English speakers.

"THIS **FISH HOPPED** OUT THE CUP OF WATER ONTO THE FLOOR" - from a [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/etrentham_25/status/919741392519385088)

"Dumpling, Dumpling Dee/The **Fish Hopped** Out of the Sea/The Little Pig Cried, When the Grasshopper Died/and the Crow Flew Away with the Bee" - from a [poem by Edward Lear](https://collection.cmoa.org/objects/333faa48-6777-44da-9d9a-8c873cf7e78d), c. 1845

"The a *[sic]* bright colored **fish hopped** out of the river and hit the water with a splash." - from an [anecdote](https://www.teenink.com/opinion/sports_hobbies/article/162052/Fishing)

"Then the limb began pulling and tugging. The fight was on! The **fish hopped** out of the water and raced back and forth hoping to break free." - from an [anecdote](http://www.marrowandnectar.com/bass-bites-of-summer/)

"My **fish hopped** out and died while I was at work." - from a [product review](https://www.amazon.com/portal/customer-reviews/mobile-media-feed/B00324X5L2?physicalId=71ry6u9pAsL&imageExtension=jpg&reviewId=R7WYZD5CXX2Q7) of a fish tank lid

"Flying **fish hopped** out of the water and did double takes." - from a humorous [one-liner](https://www.redbull.com/int-en/kai-lenny-foilboarding-hawaii)

"The **fish hopped** out of the bucket and jumped straight into the river, gone." - from a [novel](https://m.goodnovel.com/book/21000017245-280687)

"A **fish hopped** out of the tank and started breathing air." - from a [description of a cartoon](https://simpsonsfanon.fandom.com/wiki/Witch_Doctor)

"In the cold of Russia, she would wash her hair quickly so it wouldn't freeze. When it became warmer, she washed her hair in a stream, where a **fish hopped** out from her hair." - from a [news story](https://www.dailyitem.com/news/only-3-000-miles-to-go/article_8f771b9c-ce74-5f38-9418-773dd6d9d566.html)

"I stood watch after spooking the group, and was down current when two larger **fish hopped** out of the channel and tailed hard on the flat above me." - from a [fishing tale](https://anglingcompany.com/fishing-ian-slater-john-ohearnted-margo/)

"Just as Sokka said that, two gigantic **fish hopped** out of the water" - from a [novel](https://m.webnovel.com/book/avatar-with-a-system-dropped-(up-to-adopt)_17065751505335605/chapter-10-kyoshi-island_48246228877634558)

"That was the day the big orange **fish hopped** out of his small New York pond" - used [metaphorically](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bar-art/34720845591)

"I am afraid to remove the fish from the tank in order to remove the lice, simply because my **fish hopped** out of the tank once" - from a [concerned fish keeper](https://www.aquaticplantcentral.com/threads/treatment-for-fish-lice.35263/)

**These instances cited above as well as many thousands of others demonstrate convincingly that "hopped" has wide usage among fishermen, fish keepers, aquarium enthusiasts, poets, novelists, consumers, comedic writers, journalists and many other kinds of people occupying very large geographic regions to mean "jumped" when referring to the actions of fish or of metaphorical fish.**

Comment: Really? What regions? I (UK) have heard of a fish jumping or leaping, but never hopping. An animal hops when it moves along using both hind legs together instead of walking, and a person hops on one leg.

Comment: I think a sentence like "I just saw a fish hop out of the water!"  would be fine, albeit rather informal, and perhaps a little childish.

Comment: @fertilizerspike Which 'rather large regions'? I live in the 8th largest county of the UK (and in a town with a fishing port) and don't commonly hear it. Can't think of an occasion when I ever have.

Comment: @fertilizerspike Linking an example of this "very common" usage would go a long way to strengthen your answer. I (also US) haven't heard a fish described as hopping into a boat, though I agree it would be understood.

Comment: @fertilizerspike "It's very common in some rather large regions to hear "the fish hopped into the boat" or similar, despite these rather shrill protestations to the contrary."

Comment: In the three largest corpora of English that I know of, NOW, iWeb, and GloWbE, and also in COCA (Corpus of Contemporary American English), there is not a single instance of "the fish hopped", apart from one instance that reads "the Fish hopped on their bus on Friday to head down the road to Sioux Falls", so it is clearly not talking about a literal fish.

Comment: @fertilizerspike Your edits to include evidentiary support for your answer are appreciated--I have removed my downvote. Sourcing is important. Yours supports that there is informal and colloquial use, as the examples are largely messageboards and blogs.  I would note for learners that both "novels" you linked are self-published online by amateurs--at least one is fanfiction.  I see that you're a new contributor here, and may have felt sensitive at the comments. Please understand we're all here to provide the best answers possible, and the comments are for the sake of improving, not insulting.

Comment: @fertilizerspike Part of a high quality answer here is providing substantiation within the answer, and making sure that that substantiation is itself high quality. I hope you can learn from this experience, and that your future interactions here go more smoothly as a result.